# Power series of $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, pi

How do I prove that

$\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{2^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!}}=1+\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Comment: Not that it is a proof, but the answer is supported by DESMOS, so I think that the proposed answer makes sense, i.o.w. the infinite term does not go to infinity...

Comment: The numerator can be written as $(1 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot n) \cdot (2 \cdot 4 \cdot \dots \cdot 2n)$, whereas the denominator can be written as $1 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot n \cdot (n+1) \cdot (n+2) \cdot \dots \cdot 2n$.
Compare factor-wise: the first $n$ factors are equal, and then you have $n+1 > 2$, $n+2 > 4$, ..., $2n-1 > 2n-2$, $2n = 2n$. So the denominator is greater than or equal to the numerator!

Comment: For the OP: many users here tend to downvote so-called PSQs (Problem Statement Questions) like yours, and answers, too (some god will forgive them, but the poor human Jack won't). So it is in your (and community's)  best interest to improve your actual question by adding some context (your attempts, why this question is relevant to you, something along these lines). Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Challenging question. You may notice that $\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}=\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}$, then prove that by integration by parts and induction we have
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{2n-1}\,dx = \frac{4^n}{2n\binom{2n}{n}} \tag{1}$$
It follows that

$$ S=\sum_{n\geq 1}2^n\binom{2n}{n}^{-1} = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2n}{2^n}\sin(x)^{2n-1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{4\sin(x)}{(2-\sin^2 x)^2}\,dx.\tag{2}$$
Now it is not difficult to check that the last integral equals $\frac{\pi+2}{2}$: for instance, by integration by parts, since it equals:
$$ S = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{4\,dt}{(1+t^2)^2}.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 4):

One way to deal with this is notice the factor in the summand is proportional
to a [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

$$\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!} = \frac{n}{2}\frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(2n)}
= \frac{n}{2}\int_0^1 t^{n-1}(1-t)^{n-1} dt$$

This leads to
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n n!^2}{(2n)!}
= \int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty n (2t(1-t))^{n-1}\right) dt
= \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(1-2t(1-t))^2}
= 4\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(1+(2t-1)^2)^2}
$$
Change variable to $2t-1 = \tan\theta$, the series reduces to

$$2\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{d\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}
= \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} (1 + \cos2\theta) d\theta
= \left[\theta + \frac12\sin(2\theta)\right]_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}
= \frac{\pi}{2} + 1
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4^n (1/2)^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^n (1/2)^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}-1\\=Z(1/2)-1=\left(2\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}+2\right)-1=\frac{\pi}{2}+1$$
where we used the fact that for $|t|<1$,
$$Z(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^n t^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}=
\frac{1}{1-t}\sqrt{\frac{t}{1-t}}\arctan \sqrt{\frac{t}{1-t}}+\frac{1}{1-t}.$$ 
A proof is given by Theorem 2.1 [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf).