# How do I prove that a particular series converges to $\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would I show that
$$\pi=2\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2^k (k!)^2}{(2k)!}$$

This formula comes from section 2, formula 5 of
http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Pi/piSeries.html

I tried to solve this by finding an integral with a value of these terms, but could not find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power series of $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952126/power-series-of-pi) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cpi%3D2%5Csum_%7Bk%3D2%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B2%5Ek%20(k!)%5E2%7D%7B(2k)!%7D%24)

Comment: If you wanted an integral expression, one can use the fact that 

$$\beta (x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$
This leads to an integral with an infinite summation in it giving you the following integral

$$-8\int_0^1 \frac{(-6 x^6 + 18 x^5 - 23 x^4 + 16 x^3 - 5 x^2)}{(2x^2-2x+1)^2} dx$$